# Can you say Bircat Hagomel after certain "dangerous sports"

Tags: halacha, blessing, sport-athletics, hagomel

Every sport has some type of danger involved with it. But, I am referring to certain sports that are, perhaps, "inherently dangerous" or what some might call "adventure" or "thrill" sports. Examples:

- sky diving
- hang gliding
- parachuting
- bunjee jumping
- SCUBA diving

These sports seem to involve more danger than playing U.S. football. If you voluntarily accept the dangers involved, can you say Bircat Hagomel?

Comment: On that note, if there is such a high level of danger to warrant a Hagomel, is one allowed to participate in these activities at all?

Comment: Often one who flies on an airplane is doing it voluntarily and still says Hagomel. So I am not sure if it matters if it is voluntary or not.

Comment: I'd be interested to see the stats on whether bunjee jumping is *actually* more dangerous than US football or merely *seems* that way.

Comment: @TRiG good point. Especially considering all the news lately about head injuries from football. But it could be that whether or not to say the bracha depends on how dangerous the activity _seems_ rather than on how dangerous it _is_